# Terraform HTTP Request body manipulation

Tags: json, api, terraform

I am using the data source [http](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http) to perform GET requests on the FreshService API in Terraform

My code is as follows:

```
# Query FreshService
data "http" "example" {
  url = ".../api/v2/changes/7195/tasks"

  # Optional request headers
  request_headers = {
    Accept        = "application/json"
    Authorization = "XXXXXXXX"
  }
}

output "freshservice_task_title" {
  # Gets the root block volume id
  value = "Targeting Volume ID: ${jsonencode(data.http.example.body)}"
}
```

The output is returning something like this:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "id": XXXX,
        "agent_id": XXXX,
        "status": 3,
        "due_date": "2021-04-07T09:30:00Z",
        "notify_before": 0,
        "title": "XXXXX",
        "description": "",
        "created_at": "2021-03-31T12:28:43Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-04-07T12:43:55Z",
        "closed_at": "2021-04-07T12:43:55Z",
        "group_id": XXXXX
    }
   ]
}
```

I need to iterate the tasks in Terraform to do some manipulation but i am not able to do so.

I tried `toset(data.http.example.body.tasks) and tolist(data.http.example.body.tasks)` but it says attribute doesn't exists.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What's your intended output after transformation?

Comment: I want to iterate through the list of tasks and get the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say that the [body](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http#body) is `raw` response. I So I think you should use `jsondecode`, not `jsonencode`. Then you access tasks as follows:

```
jsondecode(data.http.example.body).tasks
```

or iterate (example):

```
[for task in jsondecode(data.http.example.body).tasks: task.status]
```

Comment: I tried using this 'Targeting Volume ID: ${jsondecode(data.http.example.body).tasks}' but i get the error Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

Comment: I set it in a local first and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MervinHemaraju No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: That error message is a result of you trying to interpolate a non-string value (an object) into a string. It sounds like you found a different way to get there in the end anyway, but I just wanted to note that you could've got past that error by changing the output value to just be `value = jsondecode(...)` (or the `for` expression from this answer), without including it as part of a string.